# Typescript custom webcomponent not loading in angular with npm

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, web-component, lit

I am playing around with custom web elements. At the moment I got problems with showing the custom element with angular when I use NPM. As result I don`t have any error, only a white screen.

When i manually try the customElement it`s working fine. Just by placing the TS code in the angular project self and it is working fine.(When i try it with a LitElement framework I got the same experience).

Can someone help me and tell me what i am missing?

I use a empty angular project for testing.

Added CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to the module.
Added import to the file with the element ( `import '@kireapp/viewer-test/src/hello-world-element';`)
Added custom tag in template file ()

NPM Project(based on website https://www.thisdot.co/blog/how-to-setup-a-typescript-project-using-rollup-js):

./src/hello-world-element.ts

```
class HelloWorldElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello World.</h1>`
    }
}
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorldElement);
```

rollup config

```
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import {createBasicConfig} from "@open-wc/building-rollup";

const baseConfig = createBasicConfig();

export default merge(baseConfig, {
  input: './out-tsc/src/hello-world-element.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist'
  }
});
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",                          
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",                     
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],                            
    "strict": true,  
    "esModuleInterop": false,                 
    "outDir": "out-tsc",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
  ,
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

npm publish
in angular project I use npm install @kireapp/viewer-test

When i change the class to export in hello-world-element.ts and use import {object} from in combination with template string, the result is the same.